# Bridge in graph

Tags: c++, graph, bridge

In this code, my idea is to do DFS traversal of the given graph and get the value of `low[]` and `dfn[]`(similar to tarjan), then use `low[v] > dfn[u]` to check if `edge(u,v)` is a bridge.

However, I dont know why my program always crushed when and the DFS begin, I think there's something wrong with my DFS(not sure) but I cant figure it out.

Hope you guys can help me, I'm very appreciated!

sample input:

```
5
1 0
2 1
0 2
3 0
3 4
```

sample output:

```
0 3
3 4
```

full code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<int>> graph;
vector<int> dfn, low;
priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, greater<pair<int, int>>> pq;
int times = 0;


void dfs(int p, int c){
    dfn[c] = low[c] = times++;
    for(auto& i : graph[c]){
        if(!dfn[i]){
            dfs(c, i);
            low[c] = min(low[c], low[i]);
        }else if(i != p){
            low[c] = min(low[c], dfn[i]);
        }

        pair<int, int> temp = {min(i, c), max(i, c)};
        if(low[i] > dfn[c]){
            pq.push(temp);
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    int n, u, v;
    cin>>n;
    graph.assign(n, vector<int>());
    dfn.assign(n, 0);
    low.assign(n, 0);
    while(cin>>u>>v){
        graph[u].push_back(v);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(!dfn[i]){
            dfs(i, -1);
        }
    }
    pair<int, int> temp;

    while(!pq.empty()){
        temp = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        cout<<temp.first<<" "<<temp.second<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that `dfs` can be called with a second argument of `-1` and will always use that as an index into the `dfn`, `low` and `graph` vectors, I would say it's no surprise that your program crashes.

Comment: I just realized that I misplace 2 parameters,such a stupid mistake... thanks for your help!